# Bootstrap's contextual colors

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Why and when do web developers use Bootstrap's contextual colors?

What's the point of `primary`, `success`, `info`, `warning`, `danger` classes if they already have colors assigned to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are for precisely what they say on the tin. When presenting the user with an alert for example, those colours convey the type of message being displayed.

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/alerts/

They are, of course, open to modification. You're free to set the colours you choose.